# Can we import .txt file to python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk, nlp

I am a newbie in python. I have a problem, how do we import a .txt file to python?
I have a .txt file with so many texts inside it for me to analyze with the NLTK. 
Can you tell me how to start to analyze the texts? 
Thank you in advance

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO, maybe try the tour and be sure to read How to Ask, To improve your question, you may add a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Answer (score 2):

[The Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) is a fantastic read that covers the core usage of Python.

As an example, if you have a text file `file.txt` with each sentence on a separate line, such as

```
This is a Larch.
Your father was a hamster and your mother smelled of elderberries.
```

Then you could load such a file in Python via

```
f_in = open('file.txt', 'r')
sentences = f_in.readlines()
f_in.close()  # make sure to close the file so other programs can use it
```

Edit: to include the great suggestion in the comments you could (and should) use the Python context manager, `with`.

The above code block is equivalent to

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f_in:
    sentences = f_in.readlines()
```

with the added benefit that you don't need to call `f_in.close()`. This type of structure is used ubiquitously in Python and is well worth getting used to.